# Deleted Answer From Question

Tags: support, specific-answer, deleted-answers

I posted from a guest account this question:

[Linear Diophantine Equations in Three Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142388/linear-diophantine-equations-in-three-variables)

It got one useful answer, but the answer got deleted?

I don't know why, the answer seemed to be useful.

Can someone roll back the answer?

Comment: The answer was deleted by its author. I don't see any obvious reason why (but I'm unfamiliar with the content), but the author is within their right to delete it regardless.

Comment: I have [pinged the answerer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20008890#20008890) on one of their posts. They are best in the position to explain the deletion.

Comment: [10k+ users](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can still see deleted answers. So it would be possible to copy the answer and provide it to you somewhere. [20k+ users](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) can vote to undelete an answer. But I'd prefer to hear from the poster first before considering either of the two possible steps.

Comment: BTW if you created another account by accident and if you have still access to it, you can merge the two accounts following the instructions [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8403/announcement-new-user-merge-policy-tool). (If you do not have access to the other account, you will probably need assistance of mods or SE team to merge the two accounts.)

Comment: @Meelo actually this is partially false. I think if you sign up then SE gets some rights allowing them to preserve the content (so e.g. his answer). But I don't know whether anyone was punsihed for deleting his answers..

Comment: @Internetsheriffabc123 You're mixing up the issues. When you click "delete" on an answer of yours, SE keeps the content anyway. It's not really "deleted" from this point of view. But the answer will not show up anymore in search or in the author's profile, and it will not be visible by users with less than 10k reputation who are not moderators. As far as I know there is no way for normal users to truly "delete" anything from the website (even comments are kept).

Comment: imo this rule does not make any sense. why should not everybody see the deleted answers, what makes users with 10k reputation more suitable to view it?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi you have a valid point. But apparently moderators get a message when someone deletes too many of his own answers. I am pretty certain that if they want to "undelete" the "deleted" answer, they will do it; so the right to "delete" his own answers is not really a right.

Comment: @user3680510 in what sense would it even be *deleted* when everybody can still see it? There is also a good  reason that 10k+ users can see it. It is mainly due to the fact that these users can also delete *and undelete*  content other than their own. To this end they need to be able to see that content. However access is restricted in some sense for them too. [For very precise colleagues: Yes, I know that at 10k+ one cannot (un)delete answers; I still think the reason applies as special casing on the type seems not that necessary.]

Comment: Hi, I deleted my answer beacuse it contains a mistake.

Comment: @Fabio, it's probably a good idea in such cases to edit a little note into your answer before you delete it, explaining why you are about to delete it.

Comment: @quid in the sense that it does not show up actively but there is button to view (like the edits).

Comment: @GerryMyerson good point, but a comment might also do  (to avoid the bump).

Comment: Sometimes the content is blanked and needs to be accessed by an extra click, yes, but only in cases it is deleted as spam or alike. In addition, the deleted posts do not show up in lists of posts or user profiles; except for a short while in a  list specifically for reviewing deleted content. Thus  a deleted question is once it disappeared from that dedicated list  hard to find (one needs to have saved the URL more or less). And deleted answers are always at the very end of the thread.